# How to show webpage content as full screen in embed-responsive bootstrap iframe

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have an embed-responsive bootstrap iframe control in react js apps.It works fine in desktop but when I view in mobile device the content of embed is showing half screen in iframe.please check below code and advise how to show embed content as full screen in mobile device.

```
render() {

        return (

            <div className="embed-responsive embed-responsive-1by1 flex-grow: 1">
            <iframe className="embed-responsive-item flex-grow: 1" src={this.state.url} allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>



        );
    }
```

Comment: Try adding a flexGrow css to 1 or embedding the whole inside a container grid may do the trick

Comment: can you have an example code ??

Comment: I have added flexGrowcss but sill not working.please check my updated code and advise how to do this